# Using form for button navigation and buttons do not appear

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

So I created a website for my uni assignment which had a really good navigation system using two columns, left had navigation buttons by using form and input which resulted in my site looking just as I wanted, like this

http://gyazo.com/38ed9ea8133e44c57209c6992d2a4554
I am trying to recreate a similar site for personal reasons so I can learn more about the functions of CSS and HTML together, but for some reason, even though all the code is the same, the buttons do not appear, and I can't for the life of me see why they won't display on the new site. Below is my CSS file and the HTML underneath.
If you can see why then please let me know!
Here is my CSS

```
h1 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}
body {
    margin-top:75px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    background-color:#A9BCF5;
}
.bt {
    width:1050px;
}
.bt tr {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
    align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.bt td {
    align:left;
}
```

And here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>
        Test4CSS
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <h1>Test Heading Text for the site</h1>
    </head>
        <body>
            <table class="bt">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td>
            <form action="index.html>
             <input type="submit" value="Home Page">
            </form>
            <form action="page1.html>
             <input type="submit" value="The First Page">
            </form>
            <form action="page2.html>
             <input type="submit" value="The Second Page">
            </form>
            <form action="page3.html>
             <input type="submit" value="The Third Page">
            </form>
            <form action="page4.html>
             <input type="submit" value="The Fourth Page">
            </form>
            <form action="page5.html>
             <input type="submit" value="The Fifth Page">
            </form>
              </td>
              <td>
            <p>
            This is the example text for the page, to understand<br>
            a little bit about the formatting that I have put in place.
            </p>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was easy - see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwhnJ

you had some mistakes in your quotation.

```
<form action="index.html">
         <input type="submit" value="Home Page">
</form>
```

In the line above the closing " were missing: `<form action="index.html>` This is the case for all your form element instead of `<form action="page3.html>` you have to write `<form action="page3.html">`

Comment: Brilliant! thanks loads, I had this problem the other day, I keep missing those. I didn't even recognise the difference until you put my code again.